# Display Wi-Fi only to selected devices

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I want to display my Wi-Fi network only to a couple of devices and make it such that none of the other devices could find out while searching it.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you guide me how to ban devices even if they get my Password or the network is open

Comment: One technique would be to use MAC address filtering.  That isn't foolproof but it would stop casual users.  It's typically a setting in the router.  You give it a list of MAC addresses for the devices that are allowed to connect, and those are the only ones accepted.

Comment: I am using two different router One Iball in home and Tp-Link in my office I want this to be implemented on both the devices.

Comment: Note that all of these methods are less effective than changing your password.

Comment: That's right. Hiding the name (ssid) creates a new, easier vulnerability

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot broadcast your network to only specific devices. You either broadcast it publicly with a good password, or you don't broadcast it at all (i.e. it must be added manually by each device). Don't worry about manual adding though; once the network is added, each device is usually able to detect and connect to the hidden network automatically.

## Simple walkthrough

1. Connect to your router's configuration page. Your router's IP may differ. Try [routerlogin.net](http://routerlogin.net) and check if it works.
   [image: address bar]
2. Login to the router. You will get a prompt; passwords differ between models. Try admin, password or admin, admin.
3. Go to the "wireless" section of your router's configuration menu.
   [image: Wireless]
4. Look for an option called "SSID Broadcast." Uncheck it and click Apply. Wait for the router to restart itself/apply changes.
5. Your wireless network should now be hidden. All devices which have already paired with the network should still work; but now new devices will not find your network on the list by default.

Comment: Hello oldmud0  Can you guide me how to implement this process? I am new into field of networking.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt Okay, there you go.

Comment: @JakeGould If a person does not understand what he is trying to do, he does not have any business trying to configure a router.

Comment: I'd say it requires little but tenacity once you've found the router's web page - either the setting will be in there somewhere, or it won't ;)

Comment: FYI, just direct them to the default gateway-- this will be their router's page. Start > Run > Cmd > ipconfig > note default gateway. Put that IP into a browser, then follow the rest of the info here. Almost all routers have a "SSID" broadcast option (I've never bought one that didn't have that option). Also, some routers broadcast themselves to My Computer in Microsoft Windows (it appears as a Network Device), and clicking on the icon opens the browser's admin URL or can be configured by a wizard.

Comment: Please not that hiding your SSID does **NOT** make it secure.  It is still trivial to discover "hidden" SSIDs.  You **must** make sure you use WPA2 and a strong passphrase, or else you are still at risk of exposure (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28653/debunking-myths-is-hiding-your-wireless-ssid-really-more-secure/)

Comment: ..Where are all the upvotes coming from?